# How to Pad a column value with empty space in order to trim it down to a new size using SQL statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, padding

I have a string column in a table that currently has a data length of 30 and I'm trying to now reduce it to a length of 20. If I just reduce the length, any of the records in this column that exceeds 20 would cause an error so I would like to make sure every row has a max size of 30 then trim 10 from all of them to make sure I don't have any values that will cause issues when I resize the column (there might not be any values that break this rule but I think it would be better to handle this rather than just cross my fingers).

I need to do this using only SQL Server statements but I can't seem to find a way to do it. I'm not sure if I'm just fundamentally misunderstanding something or this isn't something I can do. I've looked at RIGHT and REPLICATE but these functions don't seem to give me the result I want.

my final goal would be something along the lines of:

```
update table set column = column + (empty space till we hit 30)
then trim off anything that is > 20
```

Any help would be appreciated or if anyone can point me in the right direction

Cheers

Comment: Why pad it first? Why not just truncate? And why not test whether you actually have data that needs this? And do you really not care if you remove the last few chars in the string?

Comment: Not sure I understand the significance of 30 or why any padding is necessary (since trailing spaces are ignored in n/varchar). Why not just `SET column = LEFT(column, 20)`?

Comment: Not really understanding your problem. Is this a char or varchar column? Why not just update and use `left(20)` then update the table schema?

Comment: Wasn't aware I had to accept answers for previous questions I'll fix that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. You want to have 20 characters in every row, and your existing values are left-aligned then padded with spaces, OR
2. You want to have no more than 20 characters in every row. If the row already has fewer than 20 characters, then leave it alone, otherwise, remove any characters that exceed the 20th character

If 1, then you could do something like this:

```
WITH a_table AS (
SELECT 'Facts are meaningless. You could use facts to prove anything that''s even remotely true!' + SPACE(20) as a_column
UNION
SELECT 'Come along, Bort' + SPACE(20)
)
SELECT LEFT(a_column,20) AS left_twenty, LEN(LEFT(a_column,20)) AS len_left_twenty
FROM a_table;
```

But note that adding 20 spaces to the right of a string that is shorter than 20 characters, then using `LEFT(...,20)` returns the original string (Come along, Bort). Also note that this doesn't mean that the spaces aren't there, but rather just that LEN doesn't count them. Try:

```
WITH a_table AS (
SELECT 'Facts are meaningless. You could use facts to prove anything that''s even remotely true!' + SPACE(20) as a_column
UNION 
SELECT 'Come along, Bort' + SPACE(20)
)
SELECT LEFT(a_column,20) AS left_twenty, LEN(LEFT(a_column,20)) AS len_left_twenty, REPLACE(LEFT(a_column,20),' ','#') AS left_twenty_use_octothorpe
FROM a_table;
```

If 2, which I think is much more likely, then you just want this (i.e. the same as above, but without all that `SPACE` nonsense):

```
WITH a_table AS (
SELECT 'Facts are meaningless. You could use facts to prove anything that''s even remotely true!' AS a_column
UNION 
SELECT 'Come along, Bort'
)
SELECT LEFT(a_column,20) AS left_twenty, LEN(LEFT(a_column,20)) AS len_left_twenty, REPLACE(LEFT(a_column,20),' ','#') AS left_twenty_use_octothorpe
FROM a_table;
```

Comment: exactly number 2 I'll give it a try